# How to pass image to be later saved in another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a imagePickerController in my main view controller that allows the user to select an image. Using this image, some results are loaded in a table view in the same view controller.

When a row in the table view is selected another table view controller is opened with a bunch of strings. When a row from this table VC is selected, another table view controller with a list of movies from TMDB api is loaded and then the user swipes to save a movie.

In my app, the core data has the relationship of a single picture related to some movies.

So I would like to know what is the best way to keep track of the image selected. I know that NSUserDefaults is not the best approach.

Comment: Would probably help more for people giving answers to pick either objective-c or swift.

Comment: Please do not change tag from Objective-C to Swift again after getting answer for Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare variable on target VC's header file. Such as;

```
@property UIImage* sourceImage;
```

Before opening target VC, set target VC's image:

```
targetViewController.sourceImage = [UIImage ....]
```

Then use inside target VC with:

```
if (_sourceImage != nil){
   _sourceImage // Your passed image
}
```

**2nd Way**

Considering to use Singleton.

Create a new `NSObject` and name it to `Singleton`

Include `init` in the `.m` file

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static Singleton *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

In the `.h` file, define

```
+ (id)sharedManager;
@property UIImage* mainImage;
```

In the view controller, `#import "Singleton.h"` then initialize `Singleton`and assign your image.

At 3rd VC, `#import "Singleton.h"` again

And now you can reach

```
Singleton* si = [Singleton sharedManager];
si.mainImage = // Your image. Check if it's nil or not before use.
```

Comment: If I am not using the UIImage variable in the 2nd view controller, wouldn't it be redundant?

Comment: @thegrandhi So please tell me what are you using? Then I can update my answer.

Comment: I have 3 view controllers. image is selected in the first one. then a movie is saved in the last view controller.

Comment: @thegrandhi Well this is a way to pass parameters. Other way is consider to use Singleton. I'm going to update my answer for second way.

Comment: @thegrandhi Please check http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=passing+data+between+view+controllers+swift